# Which method to implement Websocket in Django?

Tags: django

I know that there are two ways to implement websocket in Django

1. With Django channels
2. Deploying a separate WebSocket server next to Django project

My question is which one is better for scaling and customization ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***In a short answer, it's difficult to justify as every project/application has its own goal and criteria.***

But django Channels is a recommended way to add WebSocket support to your Django application, providing features like authentication, session handling, and message routing out of the box. It can be easily scaled horizontally using a message broker like Redis or RabbitMQ and can be customized and extended to fit your specific use case.

However, deploying a separate WebSocket server next to your Django project may provide better performance and scalability but requires more setup and configuration.